# dygraphs: Make X-Axis fit to element

Tags: javascript, charts, dygraphs

how can i make the chart fit the parent element? So that Every Tick i specified in axes.x.ticker is visible. Not just when i pan. I want the whole thing resized to the parent element.

I cannot find an option for this.

My config's options:

```
            {
            colors: getColors(),
            includeZero: true,
            connectSeparatedPoints: true,
            axes: {
                x: {
                    ticker(min, max, pixels, opts, dygraph, vals) {
                        let ticks = [];
                        ticks.push({
                            v: new Date('2009-07-12 00:00:00').getTime(),
                            label: '00:00:00'
                        });
                        ticks.push({
                            v: new Date('2009-07-12 01:00:00').getTime(),
                            label: '01:00:00'
                        });
                        ticks.push({
                            v: new Date('2009-07-12 02:00:00').getTime(),
                            label: '02:00:00'
                        });
                        ticks.push({
                            v: new Date('2009-07-12 03:00:00').getTime(),
                            label: '03:00:00'
                        });
                        ticks.push({
                            v: new Date('2009-07-12 04:00:00').getTime(),
                            label: '04:00:00'
                        });
                        ticks.push({
                            v: new Date('2009-07-12 05:00:00').getTime(),
                            label: '05:00:00'
                        });
                        ticks.push({
                            v: new Date('2009-07-12 06:00:00').getTime(),
                            label: '06:00:00'
                        });
                        ticks.push({
                            v: new Date('2009-07-12 09:00:00').getTime(),
                            label: '09:00:00'
                        });
                        ticks.push({
                            v: new Date('2009-07-12 11:00:00').getTime(),
                            label: '11:00:00'
                        });

                        return ticks;
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: 'follow',
            legendFormatter: tooltipFormatter,
        },
```

Comment: For anybody that searches for a solution. 
use the option dateWindow. Example: You want the hours from 00 - 11.  dateWindow: [00, 12]. 12 so that the tick 12 is visible without panning.